Integrate Icon to display in Catia toolbar
is there any way to integrate an icon to my Catia macro ? I don't need to do it manually because this macro will be shared in different locations and with different network .
I want that everybody will have the same icon once integrate the macro into Catia.
thank you all

That is not really related to programming, more to administration of catia. You may have a look onto Environment and CATReferenceSetting
